# User Input with Gamepad Thumbsticks; How to use input.Delta

Tags: lua, user-input, roblox, gamepad

I am working with UserInputService and am trying to use the thumbsticks on the gamepad. I have gotten the detection of movement with them, but I was wondering what input.Delta.X or Y means/what it represents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/api-reference/property/InputObject/Delta

> **Delta**

> A Vector3 describing the Delta (change) between mouse/joystick
> movements.
>
> This is useful when used with the input’s position to track the
> position and movement of the user’s mouse/joystick, such as when
> you’re creating custom movement or camera scripts. Consider tracking
> input object changes using the Instance.Changed event or when user
> input changes via events such as UserInputService.InputChanged and
> GuiObject.InputChanged.

Delta.X and Delta.Y are the x and y components of that vector.

The documentation even comes with examples on how to use them.